# JavaScript show popup before submit and take additional information

Tags: javascript, popup, submit

I have a question with my form submit method. I want to submit my form to the server but for one occasion I have to take additional information from the user and post it with form too. How can I do this thing ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a JQuery, you can do it like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" id="dataForm" onsubmit="askAdditionalInfo()">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input id="name" name='name' type="text" />
        <input id='lastname' type="hidden" name='lastname'/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        function askAdditionalInfo(e){
            var lastName = prompt("Your last name?");
            document.getElementById('lastname').setAttribute('value', lastName);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

With a JQuery you can subscribe to the form's [submit event](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)